# How to deserialize a vector of pairs and objects using boost c++

Tags: c++, c++11, serialization, boost

I am having a problem in deserialization using boost library.

---

## Serialization process:

The serialization process is based on [How can I serialize an std::vector with boost::serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978311/c-boost-ptr-map-serialization-error)

- The vector that i want to serialize is the following: `vector<pair<boost::shared_ptr<QueryEntity>, string >>`
- I have no problem with the serialization process
- The problem is with the deserialization process

---

## compiler log

```
||=== Build: Debug in EntityLinking (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|

- access.hpp||In instantiation of ‘static void boost::serialization::access::construct(T*) [with T = QueryEntity]’:|
- serialization.hpp|93|required from ‘void boost::serialization::load_construct_data(Archive&, T*, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive; T = QueryEntity]’|
- serialization.hpp|158|required from ‘void boost::serialization::load_construct_data_adl(Archive&, T*, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive; T = QueryEntity]’|
- iserializer.hpp|323|required from ‘void boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<Archive, T>::load_object_ptr(boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive&, void*&, unsigned int) const [with Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive; T = QueryEntity]’|
- iserializer.hpp|203|required from ‘class boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<boost::archive::text_iarchive, QueryEntity>’|
- interface_iarchive.hpp|54|required from ‘const boost::archive::detail::basic_pointer_iserializer* boost::archive::detail::interface_iarchive<Archive>::register_type(T*) [with T = QueryEntity; Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive]’|
- iserializer.hpp|459|  [ skipping 92 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]|
- common_iarchive.hpp|66|required from ‘void boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<Archive>::load_override(T&, int) [with T = std::vector<std::pair<boost::shared_ptr<QueryEntity>, std::basic_string<char> > >; Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive]’|
- basic_text_iarchive.hpp|65|required from ‘void boost::archive::basic_text_iarchive<Archive>::load_override(T&, int) [with T = std::vector<std::pair<boost::shared_ptr<QueryEntity>, std::basic_string<char> > >; Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive]’|
- text_iarchive.hpp|82|required from ‘void boost::archive::text_iarchive_impl<Archive>::load_override(T&, int) [with T = std::vector<std::pair<boost::shared_ptr<QueryEntity>, std::basic_string<char> > >; Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive]’|
- interface_iarchive.hpp|60|required from ‘Archive& boost::archive::detail::interface_iarchive<Archive>::operator>>(T&) [with T = std::vector<std::pair<boost::shared_ptr<QueryEntity>, std::basic_string<char> > >; Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive]’|
- interface_iarchive.hpp|67|required from ‘Archive& boost::archive::detail::interface_iarchive<Archive>::operator&(T&) [with T = std::vector<std::pair<boost::shared_ptr<QueryEntity>, std::basic_string<char> > >; Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive]’|
```

**main.cpp|49|required from here|**

```
- access.hpp|132|error: no matching function for call to ‘QueryEntity::QueryEntity()’|
- access.hpp|132|note: candidates are:|
- QueryEntity.h|28|note: QueryEntity::QueryEntity(const string&, const string&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&)|
- QueryEntity.h|28|note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided|
- QueryEntity.h|15|note: QueryEntity::QueryEntity(const QueryEntity&)|
- QueryEntity.h|15|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
- QueryEntity.h|15|note: QueryEntity::QueryEntity(QueryEntity&&)|
- QueryEntity.h|15|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
```

---

## main.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    
    // include input and output archivers
    #include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
    #include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
    #include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
    //serialize shared_ptr
    #include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
    //serialize pair
    #include <boost/serialization/utility.hpp>
    
    #include "query/LoadQuery.h"
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
    
            LoadQuery lq("list_queries.txt");
            vector<pair<boost::shared_ptr<QueryEntity>, string >> queries = lq.createQuerties()
        //serialization
            {
                ofstream ofs("variations.var");
                boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
                oa & queries;
            }
      vector<pair<boost::shared_ptr<QueryEntity>, string >> variations;
       {
         std::ifstream ifs("variations.var");
         boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
         ia & variations;
       }
    return 0;
    }
```

---

## QUERYENTITY

```
#ifndef QUERYENTITY_H
#define QUERYENTITY_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

using namespace std;

class QueryEntity
{

public:
    QueryEntity(const string &, const string &, vector<string> &);
    //AFTER CORRECTION by stackoverflow. I had to add a default constructor to the clas
    QueryEntity();
    string getId() const;
    string getDocId() const;
    vector<string> getName() const;
    void setVector(const vector<string> & v);
private:
    string _id;
    string _docId;
    vector<string> _name;
friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>

    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & _id;
        ar & _docId;
        ar & _name;
    }

};

#endif // QUERYENTITY_H
```

---

Comment: the compiler is giving you an error that you do not have a default constructor.  More then likely boost needs to use the default constructor.

Comment: @NathanOliver oh so it did lol. why did he need a default constructor? Can you post your comment as an answer. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is giving you an error that you do not have a default constructor. More then likely boost needs to use the default constructor in the deserialization process.